# Sparking during electroporation of plasmid DNA into bacterial cells

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, transformation

During electroporation of bacterial cells (I work with *Mycobacterium tuberculosis*, but I think this applies to *E. coli* as well), sometimes I get sparking. I've read this is due to salts present, either in the DNA sample or the bacteria.

I use the Qiagen plasmid prep kit, which includes EB (Elution Buffer). This contains Tris-Cl. Could this be contributing to the sparking? Can you explain how this works? Does eluting with water instead of EB reduce chances of sparking?

Comment: What media are the bacteria in during electroporation?

Comment: Hi notalily, what parameters were you using for MTb electroporation?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the elution buffer does not matter (both for E.coli and Mycobacteria). I have heard this before from co-workers, but it usually is based on superstition or anecdotal evidence. I have compared water/EB elution and never saw a difference in sparking (in fact, I usually get slightly more colonies with EB).

When I get arcing (sparks), it's usually because I did not wash enough, have bubbles or have to many bacteria. Arcing is a collapse of resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Sparking occurs from having too many salts or possible not enough solution. After fine tuning my electroporation for very high amounts of DNA (16+ ug), what I've found to help are:

- Make sure you are using the proper amount of liquid solution to transform. Too little will end up sparking
- Clean up your DNA. I wash with twice the recommend amount of buffer PE, but I don't great evidence of how much the 2nd PE wash helps
- Elute your DNA clean up with water
- Drop dialyze your DNA. This is probably the most important step to prevent arcing